# How to add a rewrite rule for domain and it's subdomains in Plesk 11.0.9?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, plesk

I need to redirect a request file from all possible subdomains to one file which is located in top level domain:

```
^.example.com/robots.txt >> http://example.com/robots.txt
```

The robots.txt may or may not exist in the subdomain `httpdocs`, this rule must be exucuted first (we want to block all crawlers in advance).

The folder structure provided by Plesk 11.0.9 is:

```
example.com/
  ...
  httpdocs/
  subdomains/
    sub1/
      httpdocs/
```

`example.com` is owned by `root`.

Where can I add an apache rewrite rule that would be trigger for all subdomains?

Edit: I tested with `ping doesntexist.example.com` and the request does get directed to `example.com` which means teoretically there should be a point in processing to execute the rewrite logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing this rule in `/example.com/httpdocs/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)[^.]+\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ http://%1/$0 [L,R=302,NC]
```

Comment: Hello, the issue here is not the rewrite rule, but the execution of this rule regardless which subdomain has been requested. It also must be in one place rather that in every subdomain folder.

Comment: Right that's why I suggested `/example.com/httpdocs/.htaccess` for this rule not every subdomain's folder. But make sure subdomains have no .htaccess of their own

Comment: It doesn't work. Every website has a standalone `.htaccess` file. Therefore running `example.com/.htaccess` before `sub1.example.com/.htaccess` doesnt make sense. Perhaps putting `/example.com/.htaccess` would work, I've seen it done somewhere. But `example.com/` is owned by root and isn't meant to be modified by the user (I assume)

Comment: When I wrote `/example.com/httpdocs/.htaccess` it was was meant to be in site root of `example.com` not in any sub domain's site root. However do keep in mind if every subdomain also has a .htaccess then you will have to use `RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore ` in subdomain's htaccess